# CSS Callouts floated to both sides flow incorrectly

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use CSS to create callouts in a block of text (for things like block quotes or relevant pictures). It has to be manipulable with Javascript and work with CMSs, so I can't just embed the callout in the middle of the text block and float it. Instead, the callouts are located at the top of the text block and I use a pusher div of a certain height to move it down to the desired location.

This technique works perfectly when all of the callouts are on the same side of the text block. The problem is when I want a callout on each side. The first pusher div pushes the second pusher div down, even though they are floated to different sides and both have a very small set width.

Here is an example of the problem. The pusher divs (normally 0px thick and transparent) are the red bars on the side. Both of them should start at the top of the block, just under the header. As you can see (at least if you're using Webkite/Gecko, I haven't tried anything else), the bar on the right starts underneath the bar on the left.

http://keaton.ws/Files/theCalloutProblem.html

I've tried playing around with the structure of the HTML (Taking the pusher and callout out of their parent div) and changing the display property of almost everything, and nothing has worked. Most of the changes I make result in the text not wrapping properly. I know this is a rather obscure problem, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

-Keaton

Here's the code, with styles inline:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div style="width:750px; margin:0 auto;">
            <div style="width:750px;text-align:center;"><h1>This is the header</h1></div>
            <!-- Left Callout -->
            <div>
                <div style="width:0px;float:left;height:100px;"></div>
                <div style="width:200px;float:left;clear:left;"><!-- Callout Text --></div>
            </div>
            <!-- Right Callout -->
            <div>
                <div style="width:0px;float:right;height:250px;"></div>
                <div style="width:200px;float:right;clear:right;"><!-- Callout Text --></div>
            </div>
            <div style="width:700px; margin: 0 auto;">
                <!-- Body Text -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In these examples, the alternating left/right floats always have the same height.

http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/edge/slantastic/holiday.html
http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/edge/slantastic/demo2.html (<--why is this link unclickable?)
http://csstextwrap.com/#export

It seems that you have to sort the floats by height/position to achieve the desired effect:

http://jsfiddle.net/ge5YG/2/

Comment: Ooh, yes, that works! I'll have to make my Javascript a little more complicated, but I suppose if it were easy somebody would've done it already. Thanks!